# MySQL select value of column as

Tags: mysql, select, alias

not sure if this is possible with MySQL...

I have an invoices table containing a column named 'type'. This table only contains '1' or '2' as value. If I retrieve values from this column I do not want to have '1' or '2' in my select resultset but 'credit' where the column value is '1' and 'debet' where the value is '2'.

Something like

```
SELECT invoices.type==='1' ? 'credit' : 'debet' as type FROM invoices
```

Can we do this in MySQL?

Comment: 'Can we do this in MySQL?' review case statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html (there's a very close example in this link)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`IF()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php) statement

```
SELECT *, IF(i.type = '1', 'credit', 'debet') as type FROM invoices i
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for